# How to select element using XPATH syntax on Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

consider following HTML:

```
<div id='a'>
  <div>
    <a class='click'>abc</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to click abc, but the wrapper div could change, so

```
driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']/div/a[@class='click']")
```

is not what I want

i tried:

```
 driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']").get_element_by_xpath(.//a[@class='click']")
```

but this would not work with deeper nesting

any ideas?

Comment: do you have to use xpath? cant you use a css selector? #a .click ?

Comment: Well change how? Does it gain an ID? Does it's position change? Does it place that `a` element into another element?

Comment: sry didnt understand your comment, the selector #a .click will get an element with id a and look inside for an element with class click. if the wrapper div changes it will still work.

Comment: `driver.get_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='click']")`?

Comment: There is possibility for several <a class='click'>abc</a> elements in the page, so doesn't solve my case

Comment: How about the `descendant` selector? .... `driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']").get_element_by_xpath(.//descendant::a[@class='click']")`

Comment: `but the wrapper div could change` do you know what it could change to?  because if you knew, then you could just have conditionals like starts-with, ends-with, etc.  and as @FooBarUser states.. [use CSS selectors.](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**HTML**

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div>
    <a class='click'>abc</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use the **XPATH** as :

```xpath
//div[@id='a']//a[@class='click']
```

**output**

```html
<a class="click">abc</a>
```

That said your Python code should be as :

```python
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']//a[@class='click']")
```

Comment: Why so ? Probably I didn't get your point. Could you a bit more clear?

Comment: 'abc' in real case would be 'profile' which in Chinese would be '輪廓'

Comment: it's not your fault Arup.. the OP seems to be very unclear on what he's asking.

Comment: I never agree with matching css or xpath based on text.  Since you changed it, +1

Comment: XPath commands - https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/08/xpath-axes.html

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version 4.x, it is now:

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/h2/a")
```

To import `By`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4.X ~ 
In the real-world scenario, we need to filter the XPATH to extract the data. 
For example, below Amazon's website:
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B09NZ72B5X/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=A3VU3XJC72QOSZ&th=1

while extracting the XPATH for an item, we get "/text()" in the end. I removed it and it worked for me.

## XPATH

price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div"]/div[1]/span[1]/span[2]/span[2]')
print(price.text)

Answer (score -2):

Check this blog by [Martin Thoma](https://martin-thoma.com/scraping-with-selenium/). I tested the below code on MacOS Mojave and it worked as specified.

```
> def get_browser():
>     """Get the browser (a "driver")."""
>     # find the path with 'which chromedriver'
>     path_to_chromedriver = ('/home/moose/GitHub/algorithms/scraping/'
>                             'venv/bin/chromedriver')
>     download_dir = "/home/moose/selenium-download/"
>     print("Is directory: {}".format(os.path.isdir(download_dir)))
> 
>     from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>     chrome_options = Options()
>     chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
>         "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False,
>                                   "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
>         "download": {
>             "prompt_for_download": False,
>             "default_directory": download_dir
>         }
>     })
> 
>     browser = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver,
>                                chrome_options=chrome_options)
>     return browser
```