# python selenium how to copy text?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How to copy text with selenium xpath? 
When I writing

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rankingItem-value js-countable']").text
```

I get next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.similarweb.com/')
driver.find_element_by_id("js-swSearch-input").send_keys("www.pornhub.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.swSearch-submit").click()
#self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
time.sleep(10)


content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rankingItem-value js-countable']").text
print(content)
```

I need to copy site's global rank to a table, "22" one. How?

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list of elements. You have to iterate the elements and retrieve the text from each element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select element with Selenium Python xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035186/how-to-select-element-with-selenium-python-xpath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select required element you need to use `find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` method (that will return first web-element matched by `xpath`) or `find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]` (that will return first web-element from list of elements matched by `xpath`). Also your `XPath` is incorrect as there is no `div` with `class="rankingItem-value js-countable"`- you need `span` instead. So try following:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="rankingItem-value js-countable"]').text
```

or

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="rankingItem-value js-countable"]')[0].text
```

If you need to get "Country rank" or "Category rank", use below:

```
content_of_country_rank = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="rankingItem-value js-countable"]')[1].text
content_of_category_rank = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="rankingItem-value js-countable"]')[2].text
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you are trying to call the function on the list object.

You are using find_element**s** which returns a list of web elements and not find_element

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you trying to print the content of all the elements then the following code should work.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rankingItem-value js-countable']")
content = "".join([element.text for element in elements])
print(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rankingItem-value js-countable']")

for c in content:
   print c.text
```

It's a good practice to use **find_elements_by_xpath** because if you find nothing in the path, content[0] will be empty, but if you use **find_element_by_xpath** and you find nothing in the path, you will get an error