# submit element not clickable selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to open stackoverflow and search for a query and then click the search button.
almost everything went fine except I was not able to click submit button

I encountered error

> WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (608, 31). Other element would
>   receive the click:    (Session info:
>   chrome=60.0.3112.101)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

```
 browser=webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035186/how-to-select-element-with-selenium-python-xpath")
    z=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".f-input.js-search-field")#use .for class and replace space with .
    z.send_keys("geckodriver not working")
    submi=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".svg-icon.iconSearch")
    submi.click()
```

Comment: The element is probably moved away by a css hover effect or javascript. Or some other element consumes the click event. I would just try another dom element to submit the click event on. `#search input`, for instance.

Comment: i am anaware of css hover  or dom element

Comment: You should research that, then. It's very useful to know the basics of how a browser works when you use Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn js-search-submit">
    <svg role="icon" class="svg-icon iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
        <path d="..."></path>
    </svg>
</button>
```

You are trying to click on the `svg`. That icon is not clickable, but the button is.

So change the button selector to `.btn.js-search-submit` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to click on submit button:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.js-search-submit").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Click the element with right locator, your button locator is wrong. Other code is looking good

try this

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035186/how-to-select-element-with-selenium-python-xpath")
z=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".f-input.js-search-field")#use .for class and replace space with .
z.send_keys("geckodriver not working")
submi=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.js-search-submit")
submi.click()
```