# How to access text from a scope inside a href (selenium, python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to web scrape text from a href inside a scope, which can't be accessed through xpath as I want to iterate through a table and find the text inside the box.

[Here is a screenshot of what I want to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLsU2.jpg)

Comment: looks accessible to me; what have you tried?

Comment: if its in the DOM, can be reached :)

Comment: @SamMason I have tried, but it wouldn't show up, I tried multiple solutions

Comment: @TudorPopescu what have you tried?  anything like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035495/1358308

Comment: @SamMason as the /a in my case doesn't have any other class, what should I do?

Comment: @TudorPopescu xpath expressions can involve selectors on parent nodes, as in the linked example, just find something higher up in the hierarchy (e.g. the table element)

Comment: @SamMason I found a 'cheat sheet' that helped me organise the xpath, which helped me achieve that, but it doesn't seem to include how to implement tables in the path

Comment: I'd suggest reading a tutorial on xpath, there's no fundamental difference between different tag types

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
import urllib.request

page_url = #Insert your url here

with urllib.request.urlopen(page_url) as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    html.find(#whatever)
```

which I think should return the entirety of the html for the page, which you can then scrape for whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

According to information provided by you, you wanted to print the text, for example in this case: "3i Group PLC".
I just call the xpath link for `<a href="stock-info.php?ticker=III:LN">3i Group PLC</a>` is `link_abc` because the xpath link is not provided by you.

Here is the code by using selenium library:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("link_abc")
print(name.text)
```

The output should be `3i Group PLC`.