# Can't find element with selenium in python 3

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am using selenium to do some WebScraping but can't detect an element with xpath, full xpath, id or text.

```
<div id="cbp-vm" class="cbp-vm-switcher cbp-vm-view-list">
<div class=cbp-vm-options">...</div>
<div>
<ul>...<ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to get stuff from inside the  but can't. I can locate objects up to the "cbp-vm-switcher" stuff with both xpath and id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select element using XPATH syntax on Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035186/how-to-select-element-using-xpath-syntax-on-selenium-for-python)

Comment: can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: https://www.astetelematiche.it/aste-telematiche-beni-immobili

Comment: I kinda solved the problem because I found out that if I run a document.evaluate script in the console it can return the value but when I try to use the driver.execute_script methode it returns None.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a google exstension called katalon Recorder, it basically works like a recorder and is usually very accurate.

Comment: I tried it but all of the xpaths to the element fail, and the css selector does too

Comment: make sure that you are selecting the correct bit of the XPath, I haven't ever had a malfunction or indirect XPath using it, also make sure that the thing your trying to interact with is a button or some sort of interaction object